# Save the multiline output of 'grep | cut' to a variable

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, grep, cut

I'm new here and I'll do my best to explain my problem :)

I want to write a backup script to save all `lv`'s used by KVM.

OS: Ubuntu Server x64 12.04

Bash 4.2.24

XML file content:

```
<source file='/dev/vg1/lv1'/>
<source file='/dev/vg1/lv2'/>
```

My grep/cut command

```
grep "<source file='.*.'/>" /backup/$SRCNAME/$DATUM/$SRCNAME.xml | cut -f2 -d"'" | cut -f4 -d"/"
```

This outputs

```
lv1
lv2
```

How do I get it to do something with each output - is storing the output in an array the best way?

I've been searching for an answer for 2 days now :( I've tried some loops and pipes, but nothing worked because my grep command is too specific :/

Comment: What do you want to do with the output? Do you mean as in pipe the result to `xargs`?

Comment: By the way, you can condense your `grep` and `cut` combo into: `sed -n "s/<source file='\/.*\/\(.*\)'\/>/\1/p" /backup/$SRCNAME/$DATUM/$SRCNAME.xml`

Comment: i just need the output to create snapshots of the logical volume and then compress them. If Virtual machine could have a difrent count of hdds, so i need to read them out and loop it :)

Tried also with sed but it gave me always something like `miss s end tag`

ill try your line now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save it into an array:

```
array=( $(grep "<source file='.*.'/>" /backup/$SRCNAME/$DATUM/$SRCNAME.xml | cut -f2 -d"'" | cut -f4 -d"/")
```

You can also pipe this into a loop:

```
grep "<source file='.*.'/>" /backup/$SRCNAME/$DATUM/$SRCNAME.xml | cut -f2 -d"'" | cut -f4 -d"/" | while read lv; do
    echo "$lv"
done
```

Note however, that because of the piping, the loop may run in a sub-shell, so changes to variables won't propagate back to the parent shell.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: Arrays are specific to bash. They aren't supported by Bourne Shell, or dash (the common `sh` shells). Try it with `bash /tools/backup.sh`.

Comment: `# sh /tools/backup.sh -s vm5

/tools/backup.sh: 48: /tools/backup.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
`

damn ~.~ works with bash instead of sh, thank you very much!! >.<

I'll look at the best solution for me now :)